# How can I convert a String into a Double if the String is optional?

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, uitextfield, double

I would like to take the input into a UITextField and convert it to a Double for calculating with it.

```
func testFunction(field: UITextField) -> Int {
   let textInField: String! = field.text
           let value = Double!(textInField)

}
```

But i get the Error:

> 'String?' is not convertible to 'Double'

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can't unwrap a type. the return type of your function should be optional: `Int?`, and `return Int(field.text!)` should do.

Comment: Just force unwrap it `field.text!`

Comment: The first thing to consider is that if the String is optional then what Double value do you want to return if the String is nil.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth that’s not the case the text property default value is an empty string. The text property of the UITextField never returns nil

Comment: @LeoDabus I think you find that is incorrect the text property is defined as an optional string so it absolutely can be nil.  See this [UITextField.text](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text)

Comment: Try it yourself. Set text to nil and check its value right after it. **This string is @"" by default.**

Comment: Why does your function return `Int` if you are trying to convert the text to a `Double`? What value do you want returned if the user enters `"Hello"`, for example?

Comment: @LeoDabus you are quite correct it does internally get set to "" when you set it to nil but that is not the problem.  The problem is that the text property is **defined** as an optional string so if you try to assign it to a non-optional you will get an error.  It doesn't matter if it gets set to something other than nil in use it's how it's defined that stops the building.  Try creating a UITextField and then try to assign the value of it's text to a non-optional string, something simple like `let temp: String = textfield.text` will show the error.

Comment: @LeoDabus my bad I hadn't noticed that textInField was defined as `String!` not `String` and that's what makes the difference.  Trying to assign to `String!` will work (assuming Apple never change the default "" behaviour) but assigning to `String` will fail.  That's what I get for commenting after a hard day at work when I'm still trying to work out some nasty bugs.

Comment: Right looks like this is quite a subtle error and the message you get is not that helpful.  The problem is that doing this `Double!(textInField)` is not allowed and I get a warning along with the error that states this.  This is because you are trying to implicitly unwrap an optional which in this case cannot be guaranteed to not be nil so the compiler is preventing you from having the problem.  The reason that it reports `String?` is because when textInField is defined as `String!` it is an implicitly unwrapped optional but still considered an optional and so the it gets reported as `String?`

Answer (score 0):

[`text`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text) property of `UITextField`:

> This string is @"" by default.

So, this means that in fact this property is never `nil` so you can safely force-unwrap it using exclamation mark

```
let textInField = field.text! // String
```

Then, your method should return `Double`, not `Int`. Also if `Double` initalization fails, it returns `nil`, so your method should return optional value type

```
func testFunction(field: UITextField) -> Double? {
    return Double(field.text!)
}
```

Last thing, when you call this method, you should safely unwrap its return value. To achieve this, you can use optional binding

```
if let doubleValue = testFunction(field: someField) {
    // work with `doubleValue`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is the correct format?

```
   func testFunction(field: UITextField) -> Int {
 if  let textInField  = field.text ,
      let value = Double(textInField){
   print(value)
   }}
```

Comment: No, it's definitely not. `text` property of text field is never `nil` so you can safely force-unwrap it

Comment: How about this one

Comment: please... this code has too many errors... This code doesn't even compile